# Azure custom domain validation timeout

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to use my godaddy domain with azure web app. I create cname in godaddy dns settings. When I try to use this domain in azure portal I see two errors after validate button click without any description. In browser Dev tools I see two errors in console. It is two failed with 408 (timeout) error requests to manage.azurewebsites.net...

I try do that from different browsers and internet connections, but the result is the same.

What I'm doing wrong? How to setup custom domain for my azure web app (I see the instructions on learn.microsoft.com)?

Comment: BTW, i use .club domain

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue. To bind it with my Azure Web App, I just add a CNAME record at domain DNS Zone tab. Here is my steps:

[image]

Then I can validate my custom domain in Azure Portal.

[image]
Please verify DNS before input it in azure portal via [Dig Web Interface](http://digwebinterface.com/). Do you have any differences with your steps. If you have more concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I think it was temporary problem or something like this. After recreate azure web service the problem is gone.